# rails mongoid dynamc model fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using rails/mongodb as my backend server for my web application.

My database needs to be very flexible - I need to be able to define new tables and modify them during runtime. So I created a model Entity and a model Column (belongs to Entity) so I can dynamically create new models with dynamic columns.

To create/read/update the records I wrote a function which I can call with the entity record and it returns the class of the requested model:

I call the function getObject with the Entity record:

```
entity = Entity.find_by(name: obj)
datarecord = getObject(entity)
```

Using this function:

```
def getObject(entity)

  obj= Class.new() do
      include Mongoid::Document
      include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
      store_in collection: entity.name.pluralize.downcase

      entity.columns.each do |column|
          field column[:fieldNameOrPath]
      end

      entity.relationships.each do |relationship|
        if relationship.typ =='Belongs To'
          e = Entity.find(relationship.relationship_id)
          belongs_to e.name.downcase
          default_scope { includes(e.name.downcase)}
        end
        if relationship.typ =='Has Many'
          e = Entity.find(relationship.relationship_id)
          has_many e.name.pluralize.downcase
        end
        if relationship.typ =='Has And Belongs To Many'
          e = Entity.find(relationship.relationship_id)
          has_and_belongs_to_many e.name.pluralize.downcase
        end
      end

#     def as_json(options={})
#        attrs = super(:include => [:user])
#        attrs["user"]["id"] = attrs["user"]["_id"].to_s
#        attrs
#     end
     end
   end
   obj
end
```

This works when I use the returned object obj to retrieve data:

```
render json: { result: datarecord.all()}
```

It also works for creating and updating new records. But as soon as my entity has 'Belongs To' relationship I get runtime errors:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `demodulize' for nil:NilClass):
```

Or

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass):
```

I guess the issues is that I have no class defined for the related models?

My second problem is that I want to have other records which this record belongs_to automatically loaded. In a static implementation I can achieve this definde a as_json method which includes the associated records (see the commented rows in my code). But I dont know how I can do this in my dynamic model.

Any idea whats going wrong here and how to fix it? Not sure my way to implement this is the right weay anyway - perhaps there is a better way?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

Create all classes dynamically. While dynamically creating/instatiating classes I gave them a new name (Prefix+name of the model) so they do not override my initial class defintions which I need to seed the db (or for some internal processes). There is quite some database overhead with this: Reading the meta data for all classes including the associations and also dynamically create classes for all associated models or inheritances. So I only dynamically create a class and constantize it whenever the model changes (manipulating fields or associations/inheritance). For all other cases I use the existing class if already constantized.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid's relations code does a lot of guessing, based on the name (as do many other parts of rails or gems, like active_model_serializer or what-have-you). So if you have class User, it will assume, without any additional configuration, that it should be stored in collection `users`, by doing something along these lines:

```
user.class.name.tableize
```

I don't see the full stack trace of your errors, so I can't tell where *exactly* it's coming from, but the root cause of this is that your dynamic classes have no name.

```
datarecord.name # => nil
```

A class acquires a name by being assigned to a constant. (*and maybe some other way, but I can't remember now.*)

```
datarecord.name # => nil
FooBar = datarecord
datarecord.name # => 'FooBar'
```

Comment: Hi the reference to :user is a little bit misleading. I wanted the as_json function to include all the 'belongs_to' relationships. I cut and paste this as_json function from my previous code where I had static class User.

My primary problem at the moment is the belong_to doesnt work properly. I can retrieve recors properly with this code - but I cannot write/create records. I always get the error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass):

And I guess this is because I only have anonymous classes.

Comment: @MichaelH.: yes, I think so.

Comment: Any idea how to resolve this issue?

I found a way to make read and write working by create _id fields for every relationship . For example user_id, entity_id, ...

But this way I cannot use the default_scope method and the standard as_json method. 

I thought about looping over all relatioships after retrieving the record and add all related records manually but I guess this is not the optimal solution performance-wise

Comment: perhaps it works if I dont use the includes macro (which needs the Class for the include) but write my own scope method which adds data from my relations using the _id's ?

Comment: @MichaelH.: I don't know, try it.

Comment: Unfortunatly I am new to rails and mongoid. Any idea how I can define a scope methode which would return the the record plus its associated record?